# How to debug this program? Why isn't my 3 between 4 and 2?

Tags: arrays, c, dev-c++

https://ibb.co/gtg08qV

> The problem is to parse a series of commands that instruct a robot arm
> on how to manipulate blocks that lie on a flat table. Initially, there
> are n blocks on the table (numbered from 0 to n − 1) with block bi
> adjacent to block bi+1 for all 0 ≤ i < n − 1 as shown in the diagram
> below:
>
> https://ibb.co/WpWQBYT
>
> The valid commands for the robot arm that manipulates blocks are:
>
> - move a onto b
>
>   where a and b are block numbers, puts block a onto block b
>
>   onto: returning any blocks that are stacked on top of blocks a and b
>   to their initial positions.
> - move a over b
>
>   puts block a onto the top of the stack containing block b
>
>   over: returning any blocks that are stacked on top of block a to their
>   initial positions.
> - pile a onto b
>
>   moves the pile of blocks consisting of block a, and any blocks that
>   are stacked above block a, onto block b. All blocks on top of block b
>   are moved to their initial positions prior to the pile taking place.
>   The blocks stacked above block a retain their order when moved.
> - pile a over b
>
>   puts the pile of blocks consisting of block a, and any blocks that are
>   stacked above block a, onto the top of the stack containing block b.
>   The blocks stacked above block a retain their original order when
>   moved.
> - quit
>
>   terminates manipulations in the block world. Any command in which a =
>   b or in which a and b are in the same stack of blocks is an illegal
>   command. All illegal commands should be ignored and should have no
>   effect on the configuration of blocks.
>
> Input:
>
> https://ibb.co/pWJ9c7Q
>
> Output:
>
> https://ibb.co/Nt03mm3

input for this test:

```
8
move 1 onto 2 
move 3 onto 4 
pile 2 over 4 
quit
```

my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
    printf("please input n:");
    int n;
    scanf(" %d",&n);
    int arr[n][n];
    //this for storing their position
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            arr[i][j]=-1;
        }
        arr[i][0]=i;
    }
    //empty as -1
    char str1[5],str2[5],cmd[20];//cmd is the complete line which will be spilt
    int s,d;//source & destination
    char st[5],dt[5];//char variable of int s and d
    char* tk;//a pointer for strtok
    int quit=0;
    
    while(1){
        s=-1;
        d=-1;
        while(!(s>=0 && s<n && d>=0 && d<n)){
            fflush(stdin);
            fgets(cmd,sizeof(cmd),stdin);
            tk=strtok(cmd," ");
            if(strcmp(tk,"quit\n")==0){
                quit=1;
                break;
            }else{
                strcpy(str1,tk);
                tk=strtok(NULL," ");
                strcpy(st,tk);
                s=atoi(st);
                tk=strtok(NULL," ");
                strcpy(str2,tk);
                tk=strtok(NULL," ");
                strcpy(dt,tk);
                d=atoi(dt);
            }
        }
        if(quit==1){
            break;
        }
        //finally doing the commands
        if(strcmp(str1,"move")==0){
            if(strcmp(str2,"onto")==0){
                //empty s but leave [0]
                for(i=1;i<n && arr[s][i]!=-1;i++){
                    arr[arr[s][i]][0]=arr[s][i];
                    arr[s][i]=-1;
                }
                //empty d but leave [0]
                for(i=1;i<n && arr[d][i]!=-1;i++){
                    arr[arr[d][i]][0]=arr[d][i];
                    arr[d][i]=-1;
                }
                //now move s to d and empty [0]
                i=1;
                arr[d][i]=arr[s][0];
                arr[s][0]=-1;
            }else if(strcmp(str2,"over")==0){
                
                //empty s but leave [0]
                for(i=1;i<n && arr[s][i]!=-1;i++){
                    arr[arr[s][i]][0]=arr[s][i];
                    arr[s][i]=-1;
                }
                //move s to d and empty [0]
                i=1;
                while(arr[d][i]!=-1){
                    i++;
                }
                arr[d][i]=arr[s][0];
                arr[s][0]=-1;
            }
        }else if(strcmp(str1,"pile")==0){
            if(strcmp(str2,"onto")){
                //empty d but leave [0]
                for(i=1;i<n && arr[d][i]!=-1;i++){
                    arr[arr[d][i]][0]=arr[d][i];
                    arr[d][i]=-1;
                }
                //pile s to d
                //empty of d
                i=1;
                
                //find end(empty) of s and store in j
                j=0;
                while(arr[s][j]!=-1){
                    j++;
                }
                //piling
                int tj=0;//for iterating in s
                j--;
                while(j>=0){
                    arr[d][i]=arr[s][tj];
                    arr[s][tj]=-1;
                    j--;
                    tj++;
                    i++;
                }   
            }else if(strcmp(str2,"over")){
                //pile s to d
                //find empty of d
                i=0;
                while(arr[d][i]!=-1){
                    i++;
                }
                //find end(empty) of s and store in j
                j=0;
                while(arr[s][j]!=-1){
                    j++;
                }
                //piling
                int tj=0;//for iterating in s
                j--;
                while(j>=0){
                    arr[d][i]=arr[s][tj];
                    arr[s][tj]=-1;
                    j--;
                    tj++;
                    i++;
                }       
            }
        }
    }
    
    //print results
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d:",i);
        for(j=0;j<n && arr[i][j]!=-1;j++){
            printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `cmd[20]` is way too short to use as a general line-input buffer. Minimum `256` (if on a microcontroller, you can reduce to `64`). The lesson: *Don't Skimp On Buffer Size!* Prefer a 1K (`1024` bytes) buffer for general input use.

Comment: It's a mistake to specify *any* maximum buffer size. It's not hard to use `getline` if you have it, and it's also not hard to implement it.

Answer (score -1):

One problem that you might have is that in c you can not use variable that is input from user as the size of an array.
For the array to be n*n you must Dynamically Allocate the array's size using pointers. For example:

```
int** arr;
arr = (int**) malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
if (!arr)
    //in this situation it means that the program could not allocate memory so there is error in this case
for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
    arr[i] = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    if (!arr[i])
        //in this situation it means that the program could not allocate memory so there is error in this case
}
```

Comment: In C you *can* use variable length array. Alwo, don't cast return value of `malloc`. Also, changing a true 2-dimensonal array into array of pointers to arrays Is quite a big change.